# Swift: Get value of multiple selected UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with `multipleSelection allowed`. How would I retrieve the value of the labels stored in each selected cell?

So if I had three cell: "first", "second", "third"
And I selected the first two, it would return an array equal to: `["first", "second"]`.

Comment: Get the selected index paths via indexPathsForSelectedItems and use that information to look up the values in your backing store.

Comment: So I created an array from the indexPathsForSelectedItems, just not totally sure how I would access the data. Like, I can't do [indexPaths.row]. Any ideas? @titaniumdecoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the selected items using `indexPathsForSelectedItems`. In your example above, that should return you an array with the first two index paths for row 0 and row 1 (assuming "first", "second", and "third" are actually in that order). Iterate through that array and use each indexPath contained within to grab the cells using `cellForItemAtIndexPath:`. Now that you've got the cells, you can grab the labels by casting the resulting cells as `YourCustomCell` and accessing the label property.

EDIT: @rdelmar makes a good point in the comments below. Your first resort should always be to avoid using the cells as a source of info and rather reference the `dataSource` providing info to the cell in the first place. However, should you need to obtain a reference to the cell for some purpose NOT addressable by examining the `dataSource` (calling one of the cell's methods, etc), the steps above are the way to go.

Comment: You should not use cells to extract information; cells are for displaying information, not providing it. You should use the indexPath.row values as indexes into the array you use to populate the collection view instead.